# Exchange 2010 AS enforces SD card encryption on some devices

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync

We have some phones that are enforcing encryption of the sdcard.  Currently this issue has only presented with the "HTC Rezound."  Below are the settings in Exchange 2010.   The only differences between the default policy and the current policies are within the Password Tab and shown below.

[image]